# How to call function repeatedly after interval of time

Tags: javascript, html, function, timer, clock

I am making a digital clock in JavaScript and am trying to refresh the clock after every 1000ms using setInterval() but instead of calling function after every 1000ms it calls the function only one time after reloading page. What's the better way to call function after 1000ms?

```js
// Getting date method
var currentTime = new Date();
// Assigning variables 
var hour = currentTime.getHours();
var min = currentTime.getMinutes();
var sec = currentTime.getSeconds();



// Getting html elements
var hourElement = document.getElementById("hour");
var minELement = document.getElementById("min");
var secElement = document.getElementById("sec");


function setClockTime() {
  hourElement.innerHTML = hour;
  minELement.innerHTML = min;
  secElement.innerHTML = sec;
}


setInterval(setClockTime, 1000);
```

```css
body {
  background: rgb(230, 230, 230);
}

.clock {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #000;
  color: white;
  font-size: 10em;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 192px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

div {
  width: 650px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>CLOCK</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <p class="clock" id="hour">10</p>
    <p class="clock" id="min">20</p>
    <p class="clock" id="sec">30</p>
  </div>

  <script src="s.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: your function is actually called each second (approximately, no time precision guaranteed here), but because `hour`, `min` and `sec` variables were not updated, the result keeps being updated with the same values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your code to be called from `setInterval`

```
function setClockTime(){
  // Getting date method
  var currentTime = new Date();
  // Assigning variables 
  var hour = currentTime.getHours();
  var min = currentTime.getMinutes();
  var sec = currentTime.getSeconds();
  // getting html elements
  var hourElement = document.getElementById("hour");
  var minELement = document.getElementById("min");
  var secElement = document.getElementById("sec");
  hourElement.innerHTML = hour;
  minELement.innerHTML = min;
  secElement.innerHTML = sec;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are defining your global variables outside your function, include them and it will work.

```js
function setClockTime() {

  //Getting date method
  var currentTime = new Date();
  //Assigning variables 
  var hour = currentTime.getHours();
  var min = currentTime.getMinutes();
  var sec = currentTime.getSeconds();

  //getting html elements
  var hourElement = document.getElementById("hour");
  var minELement = document.getElementById("min");
  var secElement = document.getElementById("sec");

  hourElement.innerHTML = hour;
  minELement.innerHTML = min;
  secElement.innerHTML = sec;
}


setInterval(setClockTime, 1000);
```

```css
body {
  background: rgb(230, 230, 230);
}

.clock {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #000;
  color: white;
  font-size: 10em;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 192px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

div {
  width: 650px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="clock" id="hour">00</p>
  <p class="clock" id="min">00</p>
  <p class="clock" id="sec">00</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

please try following JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fx0tyw0f/1/. The variables are not changing because "new Date()" is called just ones on initialization. Moving it inside the function will do the job.

```
function setClockTime(){
   let currentTime = new Date();
   //Assinig variables 
   let hour = currentTime.getHours();
   let min = currentTime.getMinutes();
   let sec = currentTime.getSeconds();

   //getting html elements
   let hourElement = document.getElementById("hour");
   let minELement = document.getElementById("min");
   let secElement = document.getElementById("sec");

   hourElement.innerHTML = hour;
   minELement.innerHTML = min;
   secElement.innerHTML = sec;
}


setInterval(setClockTime,1000);
```